# drools: {} braces and conditionals in consequences - braces make a difference they do not in Java

Tags: drools

I think I must have missed something about Drools here. I have a rule with a conditional in the consequence. For example:

```
rule "Action Close When Closed"
when
    $action: ActionClose( $id: actionId, $initiator: initiator, $thing: thing )
    $open: DroolsPositVertexProperty( vertex == $thing, key == K.N_OPEN, value == false )
then
    support.deferredOutcome( $initiator, $id, K.O_NOTHING );
    support.retractFact( $action );
    support.tickle( $thing );
    if (support.LOW_LEVEL_TRACE)
        System.out.printf("%s: thing already closed\n", drools.getRule().getName());
end
```

The thing that is confusing me is that the conditional behaves as I suspect if I have if () {} form (with curly braces) but triggers even when it shouldn't when the {} braces are absent. Did I miss something in the documentation? This is 7.40.0.Final. Everything says the braces make a difference, but they shouldn't. Or I've missed something really important somewhere. Any pointers please?

Comment: I have found Drools to be very finicky about things like this on the right hand side. In some of my rules I have to actually do `if( someCondition == true )` when obviously you should be able to do `if(someCondition)` (where someCondition is a boolean.) I have no explanation for this, but I've seen this strange behavior occurring pretty consistently through Drools 5.0.

Comment: tl;dr -- just use the braces. It's considered best practice anyway.

Comment: That being said, you might want to consider using a listener to add logging to your rules.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. As it happens this is just some transitory debugging whilst bringing a system up so I'll probably delete it soon, rather than go for listeners. But good point about long term approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's always some rewriting involved in the consequence to support the custom statements such as `modify {}`.

Parsing Java code's edge cases such as "if without braces" is not that simple actually (especially because whitespace might be significant in certain cases, and in pure Java is not).

Long story short, always use explicit braces in consequences. Thanks :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the comment. It would be nice if section 4.1.9 ( Rule actions in DRL (THEN)) contained a comment to this effect. I've been playing with Drools since 6.early and still was totally caught by surprise here.

Comment: will do thank you for the feedback @Borris see https://issues.redhat.com/browse/BXMSDOC-6617